# Erro Java NullPointerException na construção

Tags: java, sql, nullpointerexception

main.java

```
package projeto;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class projetoDB {
     static final String ConnectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;" + "databaseName=projetoDB;integratedSecurity=true;";

    public static void main(String[] args){       
        String User = "dema";
        String Password = "123456";
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try{

            stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT nomemed FROM medicos WHERE crm=''");            
            ResultSetMetaData colunas = rs.getMetaData();
            int numeroColunas = colunas.getColumnCount();

            while (rs.next()){
                for (int i=1; i<=numeroColunas; i++)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "dados do médico " + rs.getObject(i));
            }


            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL, User, Password);
            System.out.println("Conexão Obtida com Sucesso!/n");

            String SQL = "SELECT nomemed FROM medicos WHERE crm=''";

            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
            System.out.println("informações do Banco de Dados");

            for (int i=1; i<=numeroColunas; i++)
            System.out.println(colunas.getColumnName(i));

            while (rs.next()){

                for (int i=1; i<=numeroColunas; i++)
                    System.out.println(rs.getObject(i));
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            }
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally{

            try{

                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
                con.close();
            }
            catch (Exception erro){

                erro.printStackTrace();
            }
        }    
    }

    void buscar(int crm) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

medicos.java

```
package projeto;

public class Medicos {

    private int crm;
    private String nomemed;
    private String especialidademed;

    public Medicos (int crm, String nomemed, String especialidademed){

        this.crm = crm;
        this.nomemed = nomemed;
        this.especialidademed = especialidademed;
    }

    public int getCrm(){
        return crm;
    }

    public void setCrm(int crm){
        this.crm = crm;
    }

    public String getNomemed(){
        return nomemed;
    }

    public void setNomemed(String nomemed){
        this.nomemed = nomemed;
    }

    public String getEspecialidademed(){
        return especialidademed;
    }

    public void setEspecialidademed(String especialidademed){
        this.especialidademed = especialidademed;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "medicos{" + "crm=" + crm + ", nomemed=" + nomemed + ", especialidademed=" + especialidademed + '}';
    }    
}
```

Erro esta aqui!

```
run:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at projeto.projetoDB.main(projetoDB.java:26)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at projeto.projetoDB.main(projetoDB.java:65)
CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 0 segundos)**
```

Como resolvo isso ? Já apareceu vários erros, fui resolvendo de pouco em pouco, mas não consegui mais compreender..

Comment: Onde estão as linhas 26 e 65 destacadas no erro?

Comment: Se sua classe principal for sómente isso, tem um erro nela, voce utiliza a conexao e nem criou uma instancia ainda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro está aqui:

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT nomemed FROM medicos WHERE crm=''");
```

A variável `con` foi declarada aqui:

```
Connection con = null;
```

O problema é que ela nunca foi inicializada, então, quando tentou acessar o método `prepareStatement()` num objeto nulo, o programa lançou uma `NullPointerException`.

Outro problema é esta linha aqui:

```
ResultSetMetaData colunas = rs.getMetaData();
```

A variável `rs` foi declarada, mas não inicializada, então essa linha também lançará uma `NullPointerException`.

---

Comment: Obrigado! resolvido!